blazor editform and submit buttons with an @onclick
In my Blazor Webassembly app, I have an EditForm with two submit buttons.
Each of the submit buttons has an @onclick handler which just sets a model value so I can tell which button was pressed.
This works fine under .Net 6 and 7, the value is set and validation and submit processing proceed as usual.
Under .Net 8, the @onclick hander is called, but validation and submit do not.
Any suggestions?
I have also tried calling EditForm.EditContext.Validate in my @onclick handlers.  this returns false when there are validation errors (as expected) but no error messages are displayed.
Update:  It was my fault.  I provided an EditContext that was a getter that generated a new EditContext on each reference.  For some reason, when the submit button had some @handler validation and submit processing did not happen. Curious, but irrelevant.
Thanks for all the feedback.
@page "/Test"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
<h3>Edit</h3>
<EditForm EditContext="Context" OnValidSubmit=@DoSomething>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <InputText @bind-Value="@this.Text" />

    <button type="submit">Works</button>
    <button type="submit" @onclick=@Whatever>Does Not Work</button>

</EditForm>

@code {
    [Required]
    public string? Text { get; set; }
    
    // EditContext Context => new(this);  *** this was the problem

    EditContext Context = new(this); // *** should have been this.


Can you edit the question adding some code?

You may be doing something out of the ordinary in your form.  You need to add some code or a [MRE].

what is the type of buttons? "button" or "submit"?
